# Is it possible to split up WORKSPACE file in several files?

Tags: bazel, separation-of-concerns

I have a Bazel project with a `WORKSPACE` and many packages. `WORKSPACE` file is quite huge, so I wonder if it's possible to break it down in separated files and import them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can extract parts of the `WORKSPACE` into `.bzl` files, and `load()` these symbols for variables and functions into the `WORKSPACE`.

```
load("//foo/bar:file.bzl", "function_for_workspace")
function_for_workspace()
```

See [`Loading an extension`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/build-ref.html#load) for more information.

Comment: Are there any examples of this? I can't figure out how to get the `load` and `http_archive` calls to play nice since `load` statements have to come first but won't resolve if run before `http_archive`.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue as @SUPERCILEX

Comment: The thing I did was making two files:
one that'll load the `http_archive` and the other one that'll load the rules.

Something like that:
`repo/thirdparty/gRPC/load.bzl` (load archive) and `repo/thirdparty/gRPC/rules.bzl` (grpc rules).


And then in my `WORSKPACE`, I'd call the `load_grpc` rule before the `grpc_rules` one.
But that's a bit contraining cause you gotta have two files for each thirdparty, and it has some issues with archives that embed other archives (like `rules_proto_grpc` that embeds `rules_proto`)